# OpenAI GPT3 Search API not working locally

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I am using the python client for GPT 3 search model on my own Jsonlines files. When I run the code on Google Colab Notebook for test purposes, it works fine and returns the search responses. But when I run the code on my local machine (Mac M1) as a web application (running on localhost) using flask for web service functionalities, it gives the following error:

```
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: File is still processing.  Check back later.
```

This error occurs even if I implement the exact same example as given in OpenAI documentation. The link to the [search example is given here](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/search#:%7E:text=openai.Engine(%22ada%22).search(%0A%20%20%20%20search_model%3D%22ada%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20query%3D%22happy%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20max_rerank%3D5%2C%0A%20%20%20%20file%3D%22file%2DLwjuy0q2ezi00jdpfCbl28CO%22%0A)).

It runs perfectly fine on local machine and on colab notebook if I use the completion API that is used by the GPT3 playground. ([code link here](https://beta.openai.com/docs/developer-quickstart/python-bindings#:%7E:text=import%20os%0Aimport%20openai%0A%0A%23%20Load%20your%20API%20key%20from%20an%20environment%20variable%20or%20secret%20management%20service%0Aopenai.api_key%20%3D%20os.getenv(%22OPENAI_API_KEY%22)%0A%0Aresponse%20%3D%20openai.Completion.create(engine%3D%22davinci%22%2C%20prompt%3D%22This%20is%20a%20test%22%2C%20max_tokens%3D5)))

The code that I have is as follows:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = API_KEY

file = openai.File.create(file=open(jsonFileName), purpose="search")

response = openai.Engine("davinci").search(
          search_model = "davinci", 
          query = query, 
          max_rerank = 5,
          file = file.id
        )
for res in response.data: 
   print(res.text)
```

Any idea why this strange behaviour is occurring and how can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on this line:

`file = openai.File.create(file=open(jsonFileName), purpose="search")`

It returns the call with a file ID and status uploaded which makes it seem like the upload and file processing is complete. I then passed that fileID to the search API, but in reality it had not completed processing and so the search API threw the error `openai.error.InvalidRequestError: File is still processing.  Check back later.`

The returned file object looks like this (misleading):

[image]

It worked in google colab because the openai.File.create call and the search call were in 2 different cells, which gave it the time to finish processing as I executed the cells one by one. If I write all of the same code in one cell, it gave me the same error there.

So, I had to introduce a wait time for 4-7 seconds depending on the size of your data, `time.sleep(5)` after openai.File.create call before calling the openai.Engine("davinci").search call and that solved the issue. :)